# How to create an Android swipe view using React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm interested in creating an Android swipe view control that looks like this in my React Native app:

[image]

Are there mature libraries/APIs out there that will help me do this in React Native, or would I have to write a Java module that accessed platform APIs?

(If I'd have to write a Java module, maybe lend me some tips/advice on how that would work out. i.e. assuming I still want to write the pages with JavaScript even if the swipe view is handled in Java, how would I load/display the React component for each tab's page from Java?)

**edit:** ViewPager looks like just what I'm looking for, but keeping this question open in case there are any higher-starred libs out there that support this?

Answer (score 1):

How about this lib: [React-Native-ViewPager](https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager), it fulfills your need, you can see how it is implemented, in fact, it is just a wrapper for ViewPager component in Android, and a wrapper for ScrollView component in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You must look for solution like this.

[react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) The best Swiper component for React Native.

just try to look once. [click here. . .](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper#show-cases)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's a carousel UI which supports that thing where you have dots on the bottom, but does it support having tabs like I asked in my question?